# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. How can I get rid of this error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

In my project I used a scaffold in a stateful widget. In the middle of the column of the stateful widget I want to include a pageview that swipes. In that page view, there are various text fields. I wrote the code for the form in a different file in a different class. I wrapped both the pageview widget and the form column for the form widget in container widgets. But I keep getting the same error: Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

This is the code for the initial screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  const Onboarding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Onboarding> createState() => _OnboardingState();
}

class _OnboardingState extends State<Onboarding> {
  @override
  PageController _controller = PageController();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 80,
                  child: ,
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 600,
                  child: PageView(
                      controller: _controller, children: [CompanyOnboarding()]),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SmoothPageIndicator(
                    controller: _controller,
                    count: 3,
                    effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                        activeDotColor: Colors.green,
                        dotHeight: 13,
                        dotWidth: 13),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _controller.nextPage(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          curve: Curves.easeIn);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      width: 110,
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          child: Text(
                            "Next",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code for the first page of the page view:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CompanyOnboarding extends StatelessWidget {
  const CompanyOnboarding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Flexible(
      fit: FlexFit.loose,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            "Create your company",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),

          //subtitle

          Text(
            "Set up your company to track inventory, orders and products",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.4, color: Colors.green),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 230, 230),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                  height: 70,
                  width: 70,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.photo_camera_rounded,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Upload logo/picture",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "picture should be in png/jpg format",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    // controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Company Name",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                      floatingLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23),
                      hintText: "Company Name",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.5),
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  //COMPANY ADRESS TEXT FIELD

                  TextField(
                    // controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Company Address(Optional)",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                      floatingLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23),
                      hintText: "Company Address(Optional)",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.5),
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  //NATURE OF BUSINESS TEXT FIELD

                  TextField(
                    // controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Nature of business(Optional)",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                      floatingLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23),
                      hintText: "Nature of business(Optional)",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.5),
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

this is what I had before:

But I want the pageview in the center between the logo at the top and the page indicator and button at the bottom

But I want the pageview in the center between the logo at the top and the page indicator and button at the bottom

Something like this:

Answer (score 3):

There are few key points.

- Using Expanded inside SingleChildScrollView will get infinite height and will provide errors.
- Using TextFiled inside Row needed to be wrapped with Expanded with to get aviable width.
- A better controll over widget sizing is Using LayoutBuilder.

```dart
class Onboarding extends StatefulWidget {
  const Onboarding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Onboarding> createState() => _OnboardingState();
}

class _OnboardingState extends State<Onboarding> {
  @override
  PageController _controller = PageController();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 80,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  // child: Image.asset("lib/assets/custigrow.png"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .6,
                  width: constraints.maxHeight,
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: [
                      CompanyOnboarding(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SmoothPageIndicator(
                      controller: _controller,
                      count: 3,
                      effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                          activeDotColor: Colors.green,
                          dotHeight: 13,
                          dotWidth: 13),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _controller.nextPage(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            curve: Curves.easeIn);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        width: 110,
                        height: 50,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                            child: Text(
                              "Next",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 19, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CompanyOnboarding extends StatelessWidget {
  const CompanyOnboarding({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Create your company",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),

        //subtitle

        Text(
          "Set up your company to track inventory, orders and products",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.4, color: Colors.green),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 230, 230),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                height: 70,
                width: 70,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.photo_camera_rounded,
                  color: Colors.green,
                )),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Upload logo/picture",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "picture should be in png/jpg format",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    // controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Company Name",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                      floatingLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23),
                      hintText: "Company Name",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.5),
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  //COMPANY ADRESS TEXT FIELD

                  TextField(
                    // controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Company Address(Optional)",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                      floatingLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23),
                      hintText: "Company Address(Optional)",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.5),
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  //NATURE OF BUSINESS TEXT FIELD

                  TextField(
                    // controller: _emailController,
                    obscureText: false,
                    maxLines: null,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Nature of business(Optional)",
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey),
                      floatingLabelStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 23),
                      hintText: "Nature of business(Optional)",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0.5),
                      isDense: true,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            const BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

More about [flutter UI](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Comment: It would be easier if you ask specific question instead of including the full project where we arent aware of your custom data and widget

Comment: Can you copy the full snippet and run again

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I'll make some changes and add some images to the question for how I want it to look.